# Wordpress. Как мне зайти в консоль WP, если мне предоставили логин и пароль только

Tags: wordpress, openserver, hosting

Мне предоставили логин и пароль для wp-admin я ввожу , захожу и следующие страницы это просто сайт, не могу зайти в консоль WP для изменений. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы меня вывело напрямую на консоль. Запрашивать у этого человека Базу Данных и уже двигаться с этой базой данных на OpenServer? Или можно как-то сделать изменения напрямую на хостинге, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: А что Вам еще по-вашему нужно чтобы попасть в консоль (админку)? Зависит от того, какие изменения Вам нужно сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проблема такая - мне прислали базу данных с другого хостинга. Я хочу закинуть базу данных на локальный сервер и уже на локальном сервере делать правки. Как это осуществить?

Comment: [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)